# Catch all redirect for create-react-app in netlify

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, netlify

I have a built using `create-react-app` and hosted in `netlify`.

In this [link](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps) it is mentioned that I need to write redirect rules for SPAs.

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

But redirecting to `index.html` is not working since no view is rendered with that URL.
I also tried redirecting to `/` like

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/"
```

but this is also not working.

How do I do a catch-all redirect for `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

To catch all the redirects use `/*  /index.html   200` in `_redirects` file.

According to the netlify docs, the `_redirects` file should be in your root build directory.

create-react-app by default creates all build files under the folder named `build`

so just modify the `build scripts` in `package.json` to add the `_redirects` in the build folder after building the app.

example.

```
"scripts": {
  ....
  "build": "react-scripts build && echo '/* /index.html  200' | cat >build/_redirects ",
  ...
}
```

If you have multiple redirects to make things easier you can create a `_redirects` file with all the redirects in your root(`/`) folder of the CRA

then in the `package.json` will become

```
"scripts": {
  ....
  "build": "react-scripts build && cp _redirects build/_redirects",
  ...
}
```

make sure that the build command in your netlify is `yarn run build`  or `npm run build`

after making the changes in `package.json` simply rebuild your code.

***UPDATED: much better way***

IN CRA(Create React App), the build script copies every file in public directory to the build folder so just put the *_redirects* with the rules in the public directory without changing anything and you are good to go.

Comment: Do I need to have the `_redirects` and `/*    /index.html   200` inside that too?

Comment: `_redirects` is the file name in which `/* /index.html 200` will be there

Comment: For details look for "Support for client-side routing" in `create-react-app` [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify).

Comment: You can actually create a `_redirects` file with the single line in the `/public` folder. The `build` command will copy the file to the `/build` directory. No need to explicitly create or copy the file on the fly. That way, you can also check it into your Git (or add to `.gitignore` if you don't want it there)

Answer (score 30):

There are two (2) ways to create [redirects when hosting on Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/).

- `_redirects` file in the root of the `publish` directory (`/build` in CRA)
- `[[redirects]]` list in the `netlify.toml` config file at the root of the repository (project)

### `/public/_redirects` (option 1)

Put the `_redirects` in the `/public` directory. CRA will copy all files in `/public` to the build directory when running the build command.

`/public/_redirects`

```
/* /index.html  200
```

### `/netlify.toml` (option 2)

Put the `netlify.toml` in the root (`/`) directory of your project (repository) being deployed to Netlify. You can add the redirect lines to the end of the `netlify.toml` if it exists already.

`/netlify.toml`

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
  force = false
```

***Note:*** These options can be combined, but remember the `_redirects` will overwrite an entry with the same source (from) path in the `netlify.toml`.

You can also use the [redirects playground](https://play.netlify.com/redirects) to convert from one format to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The main way I do this in my websites is to put it inside of `_redirects`.

Here is what should be inside of the file:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

This should be placed inside of the `react-project-name/public/` directory, or the directory that appears in the public accessible files ( example: [my website _redirects](https://cadenmf.com/_redirects), although it doesn't appear, it is there. )

Make sure on your Netlify build settings, you set the build directory to the correct one ( your project, which should be where the `package.json` is located ).

The `_redirects` file allows Netlify to route all navigation through the `index.html` file, instead of trying to load a different "page". Since React is technically a single-page application, it only uses one HTML file ( `index.html` ). The traffic from the ***pathname*** is sent to the `index.html` file.

Without the `_redirects` file, you wouldn't be able to refresh if you were on a sub-directory inside of your website. It would give a Netlify "Page not found" error. Example of the sub-directory is [cadenmf.com/defs/frontend-developer](https://cadenmf.com/defs/frontend-developer).