# Cant access react website with manual route links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, netlify

I was using netlify to deploy my app and I noticed that we cant access website using manual routes, and results in displaying 404 :

**https://edurekaclone.netlify.app**     => WORKS

**https://edurekaclone.netlify.app/courses/5b21ca3eet4r6fbccd471815** =>Does not works

Even simple routes when visited manually like /login, are not working

We have to First visit homepage and navigate to other routes/pages from there only.

I am using react-router-dom and its purely frontend without any server

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/#javascript-spas? There's a specific warning about 404s.

Comment: Thanks! rewrite rule is the thing I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix, in [documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/#javascript-spas) as mentioned by @jonsharpe, Thanks

Basically you need a rewrite rule here which should be present in build/ folder, and would enable to access clean URLs

->>

**1. Add _redirects file in public/ folder**

**2. Inside _redirects add `/*    /index.html   200`**

->>

and Voila!

This will also be reflected in the build deploy summary and logs

-->[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990467/catch-all-redirect-for-create-react-app-in-netlify)