# React Router gets 404 error when going to the website's other URL in AWS EC2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I deployed my website by copying the files in my `build` folder to AWS EC2's file hosting server.

Everything works fine if I start to browse the website starting from my homepage ([www.website.com](http://www.website.com)), but if I directly paste a url like `www.website.com/createpost` then it will get the 404 error.

[image]

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Sidebar AmplifySignOut={AmplifySignOut} username={userName} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
          <Route path='/bulletinboard' component={BulletinBoard} />
          <Route path='/infohub' component={InfoHub} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `_redirects` file in your pubic folder(in react main project)

and add this code in that file

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

Comment: does the ```_redirects``` file has no extension or anything? I just tried creating it with the single line of code in my public folder but the result is still the same.

Comment: no it do not have any extension

refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990467/catch-all-redirect-for-create-react-app-in-netlify

Comment: unfortunately it is still not working even after building the app with ```_redirects``` file

Comment: Any solutions so far @Lance ?