# How to prevent page not found Error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I finished a Frontenmentor challenge but couldn't find the reason why the Site crashes when I try to refresh in the /details/:name page. I thought at first the reson could be maybe the spacings in the path name so i fixed those but the Problem isn't solved.
In Localhost if i refresh the page there is no error but in the live server in netlify i become the ctash error.

here is the project: https://rest-kasamt.netlify.app/
and here my code https://github.com/kasamtDE/React-Rest-Countries/tree/main/src

Comment: Do you use react router?

Comment: How are you deploying the app on the server? Are you creating a .war file out of the react codes and deploying it on any server?

Comment: I deploy it like this: npm run build and then i drag the build folder to netlify @SnehasishKarmakar

Comment: @Danial yes i do

Comment: Did you verify that you have `index.html` in your build folder as the suggested troubleshooting mentioned [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-i-ve-deployed-my-site-but-i-still-see-page-not-found/125?utm_source=404page&utm_campaign=community_tracking) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `_redirect` file to public folder.

_redirect

```
/* /index.html 200
```

This means redirects all incoming requests to index.html.

[Catch all redirect for create-react-app in netlify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990467/catch-all-redirect-for-create-react-app-in-netlify)